# Python's equivalent to Javascript's jQuery or Node's cheerio?

Tags: jquery, python, api, node.js, cheerio

I'm looking for a library that has a similar API and usage as jQuery or Cheerio.

**My use case is:** parsing an HTML file for any script or link tags containing javascript/css file references.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python equivalent for jQuery is [pyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery). Under that link you can find usage examples.  You can also visit [PyQuery on GitHub](https://github.com/gawel/pyquery).

Comment: uao seems cool! is it compatible with python 2.x and 3?

Comment: @nkint: If you just click the link, you should be able to tell almost immediately. The Categories include Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, and 3.3. And it refers to py3 improvements multiple times. And it has "Python 3" PyPI logo in the upper-left corner. So, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Although [pyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) is the jQuery equivalent, **judging by your use case** I think maybe something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) could be better suited for what you're looking to do.

The following is taken from the official Beautiful Soup website:

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library designed for quick turnaround
>   projects like screen-scraping. Three features make it powerful:
>
> 1. Beautiful Soup provides a few simple methods and Pythonic idioms for
>      navigating, searching, and modifying a parse tree: a toolkit for
>      dissecting a document and extracting what you need. It doesn't take
>      much code to write an application
> 2. Beautiful Soup automatically converts incoming documents to Unicode
>      and outgoing documents to UTF-8. You don't have to think about
>      encodings, unless the document doesn't specify an encoding and
>      Beautiful Soup can't autodetect one. Then you just have to specify the
>      original encoding.
> 3. Beautiful Soup sits on top of popular Python parsers like lxml and
>      html5lib, allowing you to try out different parsing strategies or
>      trade speed for flexibility.
>
> Beautiful Soup parses anything you give it, and does the tree
>   traversal stuff for you. You can tell it "Find all the links", or
>   "Find all the links of class externalLink", or "Find all the links
>   whose urls match "foo.com", or "Find the table heading that's got bold
>   text, then give me that text."